# External RAM for dell inspiron N5110

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

I want to add an external 4gb ram to my laptop please tell me whether it is compatible or not .I already have a 4gb ram i want to add one more 4 gb ram , i checked there is an empty slot also . these  are the specs of external ram which i want to purchase.

```
G.Skill SQ DDR3 4 GB (1 x 4 GB) Laptop DRAM (F3-10666CL9S-4GBSQ)
Pins    204-pin
Brand   G.Skill
Memory Standard DDR3-1333/PC3-10666
Series  SQ
Memory Type 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 SO-DIMM
Part Number SQ
Compatible Device   Laptop
Error Check Non-ECC
Buffered/Unbuffered Unbuffered
Model ID    F3-10666CL9S-4GBSQ
Burst Length    8
MEMORY
Memory Clock    166 MHz
CAS Latency 9/9/2009
Technology  DDR3 SDRAM Memory
POWER
Test Voltage    1.5 V
```

My ram Specc:

[image]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: To know whether it is right for your laptop, we would need to know make/model of your laptop and what ram you current have.

Comment: Go to your maker's website. Check the motherboard. Go to that manufacturer's website and see tha maximum ram it can support.

Comment: i have checked it my l;laptop can support 4 gb extra ram , i think the CAS latency is also correct . are their any other factors which i have to check  like pin etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to your setup guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15r-n5110_Setup%20Guide_en-us.pdf) (specifications section) it can use:

2,3,4,6, or 8gb of memory

1333MHz Sodimm DDR3

So your choice should work, no guarantee unless the seller says it is 100% compatible.

[image]

Comment: i bought it its working good